# How does rails.bat get installed to the bin directory when installing the Rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, batch-file, rubygems

I am writing a gem, and I need a `.bat` file to be installed into `bin` when the gem is downloaded from rubygems.

The rails gem appears to do something similar, since after running `gem install rails`, the `rails.bat` file shows up in my ruby install directory (I'm on windows, but I'm sure that the equivalent shell script shows up on *nix systems)

My question is, how does `rails.bat` get to the bin directory, and how can I mimic this action to get my `.bat` file into bin when users install my gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the gemspec, you can use `executables` option to add binaries.

Rails does this in its [`railties.gemspec`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/railties.gemspec), by adding rails executable as below:

```
s.executables = ['rails']
```

RubyGems guide has a [section on "Adding an executable"](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable)

`gem install <gem-name>` takes cares of creating `.bat` file in Ruby's `bin` folder

Comment: Ok awesome. I will write an executable file in C++ and use it to transfer two files (that I will include with the gem) into `bin`.

Comment: I am still not sure who creates `rails.bat` - i will have to check further on that.  My guess is that `gem` tool does some magic

Comment: I don't necessarily need to dynamically create the `.bat` file. I really just need to package one with my `gem` and then move it and a `.rb` file into `bin`.

Comment: Okay, I just validated -  the `gem install` will create the bat file and another file without `.bat` extension (with same name) for the executables - just like `rails` and `rails.bat` are found in Ruby `bin` folder.   Hope you don't have to do anything special - just package your executable

Comment: Can I package my .bat file? Or do I need to have my .exe generate the .bat file? I would prefer to write as little C++ as possible lol.

Comment: If you look at the RubyGems guide link I shared, they are packaging a shell script for demonstration - and I tried same example - the `.bat` file will get generated automatically - it will eventually will call the binary executable that you are packaging -  so I think you don't have to write any code to create `.bat` or move it to Ruby `bin` -  your binary executable can be add-on tool that works upon your gem like `rake` or `rails`.   You can package your C++ program for which `.bat` file will be created by `gem` tool

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how a .bat file would be generated from a .exe file. In this case, I need the .bat file to just pass some arguments to a `.rb` file, and then run that `.rb` file.

Comment: Batch file created by `gem` runs a ruby script of the same name, also generated by `gem` tool  (both are present in `bin` folder) -  the generated `ruby` script actually executes the binary packaged as part of gem.  You should try installing a gem with executable to understand this fully.

Comment: Ok, I'm still not fully understanding all of this. I'll just go through the make your own gem walkthrough and play with it a bit. Thank for your help!